# All pages are visible in multi page template in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Have created a mulipage template in jquery mobile with a dialog page also.The requirement is when we click on one of the icons it should display the dialog box but the problem is all the pages and the dialog are visible in the same page allthe time without any events fired. please tell me if i am missing anything.

the code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Dialog</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="one">
            <div data-role="content" align="bottom">
                <p>
                    <a href="#dialog" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">click for dialog</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="dialog">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
                <h1>dialog.</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
                <h1>This is dialog.</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Footer</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="two">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
                <h1>page2</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
                <h1>This is page2.</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Footer</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are using too old version of jQuery.

Use **`jQuery 1.8.3`** or higher. jQuery Mobile is locked to certain **`jQuery`** version and it will not work with older versions.

In your case you are using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 so minimal requirement for it is **`jQuery 1.8.3`** but I would advise you to use **`1.9.`**

Comment: @Gajotres I am using jquery version 3.1.1 , still all data-role="page" coming  all together

Comment: Still broken at jQuery ver 3.6.0.

Comment: My advice, switch to something else, jQuery Mobile is long dead.